# What kind of attacks can be performed off a local network?

Tags: passwords

I have been working with programs like Kali Linux, Cain, etc., and I have noticed that for the most part the biggest password stealing attacks must be performed on the same network as the victim (for instance, MiTM and most of the attacks on Metasploit). What forms of attack (especially designed to steal passwords) could be performed on my computer while I am on a different network from the attacker?

EDIT: Sorry, this was a bit open ended because I didn't know much about the subject. What kind of attack might one use to exploit security vulnerabilities in my system? So I don't particularly care about Trojans or Phishing, because those are mainly attacks against the user. However, as an example, could someone set up a website using a free hosting service and upload script to it that appears to be a JScript based game but really also exploits a Java vulnerability and downloads a backdoor? I suppose what I really want to know is if you had to hack my computer without accessing it physically or connecting to my network how would you do it? Thanks!

Comment: Still very broad after the edit. The problem is that there are too many vectors to consider. Attacking the web browser is common, attacking the user is easiest. Turn the question around: what do you want to protect against? As it stands, you need a pentesting course to answer your question.

Comment: @schroeder, Sorry. I would like to know the most popular attack, and also the most effective. Since I do not know what attacks are possible, I cannot know what I would like to defend against.

Comment: Frankly, social engineering is the most effective when you want to target a particular system. To defend, you need to look at the browser, email client, and user education.

Comment: @schroeder So the only thing that can be exploited purely by a program is the browser, correct? I am discounting e-mail as "purely by a program" because it involves tricking a reader into opening it.

Comment: This is still a completely wide open question - many books can - and have been - written just about this. I suggest you start reading up on the subject, take any good InfoSec 101 book or course, or just read up on educational websites....

Comment: @AviD That sounds like a great idea. I have already read applied cryptography, but do you have any suggestions aside from that?

Comment: Look here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books . Most of those are not good questions (recommendation requests get closed pretty fast), but many good books are mentioned.